# no validation takes place and also no error occurs

Tags: android, validation, toast

**savebutton.setonclicklistenser:**

```
if(edittext.getText().equals(""))

    {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"enter data first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }
else

{

//all the view insert data query stuff

//toast.maketext("data inserted");

}
```

but It shows
**result: "data inserted"**

on click view button it shows all the empty slots which i added as string on `tv.append("slot 1 "+slot1+"");`
veiws all the slots like "slot1" string i passed in append method.

Comment: Please format your code-lines in codeblocks, to improve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `if(edittext.gettext().equals(""))` condition to `if(edittext.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))` add `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks. trim() will remove white space from string of edittext.

Comment: np and yes i know, even tho it is unnecessary in some cases but for validation purposes, it is.

Comment: replace .equals(null) with .equals("")

Comment: i "literally" tried that as well @AhmadAlsanie . Had same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This

```
if(edittext.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter data first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
else
{
 //all the view insert data query stuff

//toast.maketext("data inserted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can write this**

```
if(edittext.getText().toString().equals("")){
          Toast.maketext(getApplicationcontext(),"enter data first",toast.length_long);
}
```

**Instead of this**

```
if(edittext.gettext().equals("")){
               Toast.maketext(getbasecontext(),"enter data first",toast.length_long); 
}
```

Comment: please give your problem detail.

Comment: Try to add double quotes instead of null. like if(mwf_slot1.getText().toString().equals("")) then let me know.

Comment: i added null back after trying the double quotes, Kinjal. :(
when i commented tried it to your answer. i literally did try it.

Comment: Your image is not displayed please check it out then Let me know

Comment: i hope it works now. http://oi61.tinypic.com/25jbhnb.jpg
i tried with both (""), (null) on this method as well now..